# Font size changes in tex document after referencing a label

Tags: fontsize, tex-core

I am trying to reference a label, but when I do so the font size changes as shown below

```
over the unknown measurable on $\R$ vector functions $f(x) = \left( f_1(x), ..., f_n(x) \right)^T$ 
and $\varphi(x) = \left( \varphi_1(x), ..., \varphi_n(x) \right)^T$ respectively ($T$ is the 
sign of transposition). In the systems (\ref{eq: 1}) and (\ref{eq: 2}) the matrix kernel 
$K(x, t) = \left( K_{ij}(x,t)\right)_{i,j = 1}^{n \times n} $ satisfies the following conditions:
```

[image]

The font size changed after the reference (1.1). How this can be solved?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem. It is not in showed document fragment.

Comment: Unrelated: Note that all those `\left(...\right)` in the example are irrelevant, they do nothing. In general don't use `\left...\right` within `$....$` they often end up being too large.

Comment: It seems like for some reason your `\ref` command changed the font size. This is not normal behavior, meaning that somewhere else in the code this command has been modified (either in your document itself, or through a `\usepackage`/`\include`/`\input` statement that loads external code). To answer your question we need to see the code that caused the modification. Because your full document is probably very big, you can try to delete as much content, usepackage statements etc. as you can while the problem still persists, then post the full remaining document here as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have code equivalent to

[image]

Simply remove the offending definition of `\ref`.

You can add `\typeout{qqq: \meaning\ref}` at various points then the log will show the offending package where `\ref` changes.

```
\typeout{0: \meaning\ref}
\documentclass{article}
\typeout{1: \meaning\ref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\typeout{2: \meaning\ref}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand\ref{\normalsize\oldref}
\typeout{3: \meaning\ref}
\begin{document}
\typeout{4: \meaning\ref}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq: 1}
   a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq: 2}
   a=b
\end{equation}

\tiny
over the unknown measurable on $\R$ vector functions $f(x) = \left( f_1(x), ..., f_n(x) \right)^T$ 
and $\varphi(x) = \left( \varphi_1(x), ..., \varphi_n(x) \right)^T$ respectively ($T$ is the 
sign of transposition). In the systems (\ref{eq: 1}) and (\ref{eq: 2}) the matrix kernel 
$K(x, t) = \left( K_{ij}(x,t)\right)_{i,j = 1}^{n \times n} $ satisfies the following conditions:

\end{document}
```